# Producing a regplot in metafor for multivariable model with a spline (marginal relation)

Tags: r, regression, spline, metafor

I was trying to produce a regression plot with the `regplot()` in the `metafor` package, fitting a continuous predictor as a restricted cubic spline through the use of the `rms` package in R, in the context of a multivariable regression.

However, after carefully reviewing all the examples listed here: https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/regplot.html, I was unable to reproduce the plot desired (i.e., the regression plot of the continuous predictor modelled as a restricted cubic spline).

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(metafor)
library(rms)
dat <- dat.bcg

#Fitting the meta-analysis
dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat)

#Fit a multivariable meta-regression with ablat as a rcs with 3 knots
res <- rma(yi, vi, mods = ~ rcs(ablat,3)+year+alloc, data=dat)
```

The result of the model is reported below:

```
Model Results:

                     estimate       se     zval    pval      ci.lb    ci.ub   ​ 
intrcpt              -24.8731  38.8083  -0.6409  0.5216  -100.9361  51.1898    
rcs(ablat, 3)ablat     0.0043   0.0290   0.1497  0.8810    -0.0525   0.0611    
rcs(ablat, 3)ablat'   -0.0504   0.0466  -1.0799  0.2802    -0.1418   0.0410    
year                   0.0125   0.0196   0.6384  0.5232    -0.0259   0.0509    
allocrandom           -0.3525   0.4090  -0.8618  0.3888    -1.1541   0.4491    
allocsystematic       -0.2187   0.4832  -0.4526  0.6508    -1.1659   0.7284
```

Now if I want to produce a regplot of this model (i.e., the marginal relationship between the spline predictor and the effect size), I must use:

```
regplot(res, mod="rcs(ablat, 3)ablat")
```

But the resulting plot (reported below) seems to me taking into account only the first term of the spline-modelled variable:
[image]

Consistently, I am able to produce another plot if I change my call of regplot to `regplot(res, mod="rcs(ablat, 3)ablat'")` (i.e., specifying as the moderator variable the non-linear term of ablat in the multivariable regression model).

I have tried to pre-specify prediction through the `predict()` function and then passing the argument to `regplot`, but I am still unable to produce the desired plot.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:non_linear_meta_regression  for a tutorial on using splines together with metafor.

Comment: @Wolfgang thank you for your reply, but I was unable to create prediction for a multivariabel model since I do not know how to specify the newmods argument for the other terms of the regression...

Comment: Set them equal to their means for the marginal relationship.

Comment: @Wolfgang thank you - so in the example, given that the alloc is a factor variable, should I impose "0" as the newmods argument for the two levels? I understand the interpretation of setting continuous variable equals to their mean, but for factor I am unsure how to set them at their reference level

Comment: Take a look at: https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:computing_adjusted_effects

Comment: Thank you again. I've edited my post to reflect a proposed answer based on your suggestions.

Comment: Looks good, nicely done! For the purposes of this website, it might be better to actually post this as an answer, which you can then mark as the accepted answer. This way, this question won't remain an unanswered in the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting here the solution, that I have managed to arrange after the inestimable help of @Wolfgang in the comments, just in case someone else needs in the future:

```
res <- rma(yi, vi, mods = ~ rcs(ablat,3)+year+alloc, data=dat)

knots <- attr(rcs(model.matrix(res)[,2], 3), "parms")
knots
xs <- seq(10,60, length=500)
sav <- predict(res, newmods=cbind(rcspline.eval(xs, knots, inclx=TRUE),colMeans(model.matrix(res))[4],
                                  colMeans(model.matrix(res))[5],colMeans(model.matrix(res))[6]))
tmp <- regplot(res, mod=2, pred=sav, xvals=xs, las=1, digits=1, bty="l",
               psize=.20/sqrt(dat$vi), xlab="Predictor", main="Restricted Cubic Spline Model", transf=exp)
abline(v=knots, lty="dotted")
points(tmp)
```

And here's the resulting plot, with represent the marginal relation of `rcs(ablat,3)` with the effect size:

[image]